# Is it possible to run hostnamectl in ArchLinux Docker container?

Tags: docker, ansible, archlinux

I want to create a role for Ansible to configure my network. I'm also trying to test my role with molecule in an Arch Linux Docker container.
Inside my role I'm using Ansible's hostname module. But when I run my molecule test I get the following error message: "Could not set property: Failed to set static hostname: Device or resource busy."

I'm new to Docker, so maybe its some missing capabilities in my configuration. Maybe something is wrong in my Dockerfile. But maybe its not possible at all to get the hostnamectl command running in an Arch Linux Docker container.
I've installed the inetutils package and ran the hostname command, which worked. But at least Ansibles hostname module doesn't care about the hostname command.

I hope you can give me some information on my questions!

Here are the files I'm using:

network/defaults/main.yml

```
---
network_hostname: archlinux
```

network/molecule/default/converge.yml

```
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - network
```

network/molecule/default/molecule.yml

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint: |
  set -e
  yamllint .
  ansible-lint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: marcstraube/docker-archlinux-base-ansible:latest
    pre_build_image: true
    privileged: true
    command: "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"
    env:
      container: docker
    capabilities:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /run/lock
      - /tmp
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    host_vars:
      instance:
        ansible_user: ansible
scenario:
  name: default
  create_sequence:
    - create
  check_sequence:
    - destroy
    - create
    - converge
    - check
    - destroy
  converge_sequence:
    - create
    - converge
  destroy_sequence:
    - destroy
  test_sequence:
    - lint
    - destroy
    - syntax
    - create
    - converge
    - idempotence
    - destroy
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

network/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Set hostname 
  become: true 
  hostname: 
    name: "{{ network_hostname }}"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The module ansible.builtin.hostname uses the hostnamectl command to change the hostname. The hostnamectl command, on the other hand, tries to replace the /etc/hostname file, which ends with the error in the container "Could not set property: Failed to set static hostname: Device or resource busy"

This can be verified by checking with the strace command what operations on files hostnamectl performs, in the output we will get:

```
rename("/etc/.#hostnamesCzCPh", "/etc/hostname") = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

The reason for this is that container files like /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf are actually mounted from an external docker directory. You can check this by running the findmnt command in the container:

```
|-/etc/resolv.conf           /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/48bb04a70b39f1cebb06bf8f9ddfb181b38155c429030fa3f3c11dba415675d7/resolv.conf]
|                                            ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
|-/etc/hostname              /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/48bb04a70b39f1cebb06bf8f9ddfb181b38155c429030fa3f3c11dba415675d7/hostname]
|                                            ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
|-/etc/hosts                 /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/48bb04a70b39f1cebb06bf8f9ddfb181b38155c429030fa3f3c11dba415675d7/hosts]
|                                            ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
```

So, you can't replace these files in running container. You can only change their content.